# How does the small angle approximation lead to 0 here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, approximations

I'm finding the equations of motion of a mass attached to four springs in a box.  See picture:

[image]

In the prompt, we're instructed to use "the small-oscillations
approximation, and neglect terms of order $\frac{x^2}{a^2}$ , $\frac{y^2}{a^2}$ , and $\frac{xy}{a^2}$".  This all makes perfect sense to me.

Using both force diagrams and the Lagrangian approach, I find the equations of motion.  I have the solution, but I do not see how it is possible to reach that solution.

For example, let's find the x-component of the force from the spring at the "top" of the box.  The length of the spring for an arbitrary x, y is $\sqrt{x^2 + (a-y)^2}$, and so our total force vector is $F_1$ = $K_2\left(a-\sqrt{x^2 + (a-y)^2}\right)$.  And taking the x-component we have:

$$
F_{1x} = K_2\left(a-\sqrt{x^2 + (a-y)^2}\right) \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + (a-y)^2}}
$$

And I am told from the solutions that $F_{1x} \approx 0$.  I cannot see how this is possible.  I've tried using the approximation $(1+x^2)^{-1/2} \approx (1-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$, but it seems no matter what I do I fail to reach 0.

Does anyone see how small angle approximation can lead to getting $F_{1x} = 0$ here?

Comment: Could you more precisely restate that as $F_{1x}\in o(f(a,\,x\,y))$ for some function $f$? Note$$a-\sqrt{a^2+k}=a(1-\sqrt{1+k/a^2})\sim-k/(2a)\in o(1)$$if $k\in o(a)$.

Comment: expand $F_{1x}$ into a Taylor series wrt $x$ and the first term is $-(y-2a)x/(y-a)^2$

Comment: @J.G. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking me there.  If $k = (a-y)^2$, continuing on your equation, I don't get 0, just some combination of a's, y's, and x's that you cannot use the small approximation to eliminate.

Comment: @hyportnex Carrying out the Taylor expansion, I do not get that, and neither does wolframalpha - did you make a mistake?  Even if you do get that, expansion, once again I don't see how that leads to 0.

Comment: Take $y = 0$. For $x> 0$ you have the left spring stretched which returns to it and the right spring, compressed, which pushes. The two forces are in the same direction and you have to find $-2kx$. So there is an error in your calculation.

Comment: I used maxima.... , bad typing, no square in the denominator. should be $-(y-2a)x/(y-a)$, the result for you is the same.

Comment: Technically it would be $k=(a-y)^2+x^2-a^2=x^2+y^2-2ay$.

Answer (score 1):

the force $F_{1x}$ is:

$$F_{1x}={\frac {K_{{1}} \left( \sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-2\,ya+{a}^{2}}-a
 \right) x}{\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-2\,ya+{a}^{2}}}}
$$

take the Taylor series for the denominator

$$\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-2\,ya+{a}^{2}}\overset{\text{Taylor}}{\mapsto}=a$$
and for the nominator
$$K_{{1}} \left( \sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-2\,ya+{a}^{2}}-a \right) x\overset{\text{Taylor}}{\mapsto}=-K_{{1}}yx=0$$

thus $F_{1x}=\frac{0}{a}=0$

Comment: Thank you.  Two questions - in my Taylor series expansion for the denominator, I get $a-y$, did you expand only in terms of x?  When I included y I got the extra -1 term from the partials wrt y.  Second question is how legitimate is an approximation that is a ratio of two Taylor series?  Seems borderline to me, but you got the answer so I'm assuming this is what was intended by the question.

Comment: the Taylor series expansion for the denominator second order is $~\sqrt {a}\sqrt {a-2\,y}$ , you obtain also zero. your second question I am not sure about this ?

Comment: Taylor expansion second order is $f(x,y)=f \left( 0,0 \right) +D_{{1}} \left( f \right)  \left( 0,0 \right) x+D
_{{2}} \left( f \right)  \left( 0,0 \right) y~$ where $D_1=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}~$ and $~D_2=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$